# How to reliably choose audio profiles/sinks/ports from the command line?

Tags: fedora, audio, kde, profile

I have a Linux box (Fedora 38 KDE with PipeWire) that has an internal speaker (I.S.) (reasonable quality to play notifications, TTS, etc), and I have a nice set of external speakers (E.S.) to play decent music. This box a Dell Optiplex 7000 SSF.

There are two ways I can plug the E.S. to my system: either with a rear jack in the box, or at the monitor jack, which is connected to the computer through HDMI. Both work.

The configuration that I have now is *the E.S. plugged to the monitor* (otherwise, the I.S. are disabled!!). Then I can switch between I.S. and E.S. doing this:

```
card="`pactl list cards | grep Name: | sed 's/.*: *//'`"
```

and then either

```
pactl set-card-profile $card "output:analog-stereo"  # I.S.
```

or

```
pactl set-card-profile $card "output:hdmi-stereo"    # E.S.
```

Yet, I have some problems:

1. When I plug the E.S. to the rear of the computer, the I.S. appear as disabled in Settings > Audio. Yet, I can hear some notifications in the I.S., but I do not know **how to send sound to the E.S. when connected to the rear jack of the computer**. Why does Fedora disable them, and why only partially? When connected to the monitor the I.S. do not appear as disabled.
2. I would like the system to send sound to the E.S. *if* they are **ON**, otherwise send it to the I.S. I have other box with USB E.S., and Fedora switches automatically between them without any intervention of my part, but not with this old E.S. connected through jack. However, I do not see any difference in the system: **Is there any way for Linux to know if the E.S. are ON or OFF** when connected to the rear jack?
3. **How can I force sound through the I.S. when the E.S. are connected to the rear jack?**

Sorry for the many questions...